# 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' hangs at 100%

Tags: apt, nautilus, dpkg, dropbox

I tried to install python's `enchant` incorrectly with `sudo apt-get install enchant`.  I know now that this was not correct, but it began installing dropbox... no clue why that happened so I panicked and tossed a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> at it.

This gave me a `dpkg` error. Now when I try to let dpkg fix itself it "installs" dropbox and hangs at 100% forever (like the past hour).

If I do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> I am in the same boat as before, if I do nothing `apt-get` is locked.  Any ideas on how I can kill this beast?

### Here is what I am seeing on my Terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up nautilus-dropbox (0.7.1-2) ...

Dropbox is the easiest way to share and store your files online. Want to learn more? Head to http://www.dropbox.com/

Downloading Dropbox... 100%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK looks like I found a very simple answer!

I just run:

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus-dropbox
```

Then it worked.